# Main domain doesn't show anything just "working"?

Tags: database, wordpress, dns, hosting

I know my title is little Dumb. My problem is I moved my `wordpress` site to new hosting and everything works fine except when I type main domain on browser it does not show anything just a white page with a "working" on it.

[My domain](http://www.hastishop.com/)

Every other links are working OK. So what is the problem here?

[Another page](http://www.hastishop.com/shop)

Answer (score 0):

1]Navigate to the directory where your WordPress files are located.

2]Open the wp-content folder.

3]Inside the wp-content folder, locate the plugins folder.

4]Rename the plugins folder.

5]Log in to your WordPress Dashboard.